# Suggestions on how to order a list of strings to increase compression performance?

Tags: string, sorting, compression, heuristics

Say you have a huge set of strings:

```
{'Ape','Bed','Car','Desk','Edge',...}
```

and you have to write the set to a file. But the order in which the strings appear is arbitrary (you only need to store/retrieve the set).

Since the set can be huge, you want to compress it, for instance using `gzip`. I am interested in ways to *sort* the set such that compression rates are optimized. Alphabetically sorting looks like a valuable candidate since it means that if `gzip` compresses a "frame", it will see a lot of strings that start with the same substring: in the beginning it could for instance encode `AAA` shorter where in the end `ZZY` might be encoded short.

I already ran a few tests by sorting strings. For instance a test-set `strings` (92 274 strings) generates:

```
-rw-rw-r-- 1 willem willem 296K Jan 19 18:52 strings_norm.gz
-rw-rw-r-- 1 willem willem 419K Jan 19 18:52 strings_shuf.gz

-rw-rw-r-- 1 willem willem 241K Jan 19 19:00 strings_norm.7z
-rw-rw-r-- 1 willem willem 374K Jan 19 19:01 strings_shuf.7z
```

Where `_norm` is the sorted list and `_shuf` is its shuffled counterpart. The strings are simply encoded originally with utf-8 and new lines between the words. A more accessible test set is probably the American dictionary you find on most Linux distros (probably located in `/usr/share/dict/american-english`; 99 171 words):

```
-rw-rw-r-- 1 willem willem 208K Jan 19 19:40 american_norm.7z
-rw-rw-r-- 1 willem willem 250K Jan 19 19:39 american_norm.gz
-rw-rw-r-- 1 willem willem 352K Jan 19 19:40 american_shuf.7z
-rw-rw-r-- 1 willem willem 439K Jan 19 19:40 american_shuf.gz
```

These are generated with:

```
sort /usr/share/dict/american-english | gzip > american_norm.gz
shuf /usr/share/dict/american-english | gzip > american_shuf.gz
sort /usr/share/dict/american-english | 7z a american_norm.7z -si
shuf /usr/share/dict/american-english | 7z a american_shuf.7z -si
```

As you can see we gain an additional 29%-43% with `gzip` and 35%-40% with `7z`. A first remark is that by sorting both compression algorithms perform better so the hypothesis is that although compression rates will differ one can say there are "good" orderings and "bad" ones: ones where nearly all compression algorithms achieve better rates than with other orderings. Of course it is possible that a "shuffled" dataset will perform better, but the odds are probably not that high. I was wondering if there exist more advanced methods. After all by sorting the strings will likely start with the same substring, but another way to order them might find strings that have a large substring in common, like `apple`, `apples`, `dapple`, `pineapple`, etc.

The problem is probably - like most interesting problems - NP-hard, but I was wondering if there exist some heuristics that we can use to optimize string compression given the order of the string does not matter.

Comment: Perhaps sorting by frequency a la Huffman tree would improve compression.   `Dog Doggy Doggie Dot Dim Cat Car Zeta Alpha`?

Answer (score 1):

The differences in file sizes alone suggest the alphabetical ordering is close to optimal.

Suppose a compression algorithm can compress a list of ***n*** words down to ***b*** bits for some specific ordering. It could then compress any other ordering of those ***n*** words down to approximately ***b* + log2(*n*!)** bits by outputting the compressed version of the optimal ordering (***b*** bits), a string identifying one of the other ***n*!** orderings (**log2(*n*!)** bits), and a little metadata.

For a list of 99,171 words, this amounts to a difference of [1,502,940 bits](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i2d=true&i=log2%5C%2840%2999171%21%5C%2841%29), or about 183KB, very close to the 189KB difference you found with gzip.

However, you should be able to outperform general purpose compression algorithms with a bespoke algorithm that takes advantage of the structure of your specific data. I found this Stack Overflow question while wondering if I could improve the compression of the Wordle dictionary, which Brotli compresses from 83KB to 28KB. By storing only the first word, the subsequent changed suffixes, and a 110 byte JavaScript decoder, [I was able to outperform Brotli](https://iamkate.com/code/wordle-dictionary/) with a 21KB output that Brotli further compressed to 14KB.

Comment: Excellent answer.